# got error while upload video in youtube Error: Login Required

Tags: node.js, video, youtube, youtube-api

While upload video in youtube in node using Key I got Login required error.

```js
'use strict';

var google = require('../../lib/googleapis');
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
var API_KEY = "AI..............xE";

var FILENAME = 'test4.mp4';


var youtube = google.youtube({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: API_KEY
});
function uploadVideo () {
  var req = youtube.videos.insert({
    part: 'id,snippet,status',
    notifySubscribers: false,
    resource: {
      snippet: {
        title: 'New video',
        description: 'Testing YouTube upload via Google APIs Node.js Client'
      },
      status: {
        privacyStatus: 'private'
      }
    },
    media: {
      body: fs.createReadStream(FILENAME)
    }
  }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error: ' + err);
    }
    if (data) {
      console.log(util.inspect(data, false, null));
    }
    process.exit();
  });

 
uploadVideo();
```

got error like 
Error: Error: Login Required

how i upload video using key in node.js.

upload video without using oauth redirect url.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to upload without credentials, hence the log-in process. Anyway, try using the [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#retrieve-authorization-code) by google. The part you're looking for is in the Authorizing and authenticating section. Also, check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801172/upload-a-video-to-youtube-with-node-js) if you need more reference on uploading youtube using nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is impossible to upload videos with API keys.**

From a technical point of view, API keys are not tied to a specific YouTube channel, but to a Google Cloud Console project. That means even if YouTube allowed API keys as authentication for uploading videos, they wouldn't know which channel to upload to.

For all write actions (e.g. uploading videos), [proper authentication via OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) is required.